# How to do an "UPDATE WHERE" operation in pig latin involving variables from two aliases with an unknown number of records?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to Pig. Here is some pseudo-code for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
FOREACH split_records {
  UPDATE updated_volume SET 
  open=updated_volume.open*split_records.multiply_by/split_records.divide_by,
  close=updated_volume.close*split_records.multiply_by/split_records.divide_by

  WHERE split_records.symbol=updated_volume.symbol AND 
  updated_volume.date < split_records.split_date
}
```

And here is what I have so far in terms of pig code:

```
FOREACH split_records {
  SPLIT updated_volume INTO split_yes IF updated_volume.symbol==split_records.symbol AND 
  updated_volume.date < split_records.splitDate, split_no IF 
  updated_volume.symbol!=split_records.symbol OR 
  updated_volume.date > split_Records.splitDate;

  updated_splits = FOREACH split_yes GENERATE
  symbol,
  date,
  (split_yes.open*split_records.multiply_by/split_records.divide_by) AS open,
  (split_yes.close*split_records.multiply_by/split_records.divide_by) AS close;

  updated_volume = UNION updated_splits, split_no;
};
```

The above code gives me the error: mismatched input 'SPLIT' expecting GENERATE, so it definitely won't work.  But basically I am trying to emulate an "UPDATE..WHERE" operation where the WHERE condition is dependent on a variable which is the result of iterating through another set of records, the length/count of which is unknown.

I am under the vague impression that Pig isn't the kind of language that was meant for iteration, so I am open to any method by which to accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, don't ask questions like "Would something like this work?". Check if it works by yourself and then, if you have some problems, ask the question.

Comment: Hi zero, you're right, but I've seen some questions where people just ask "How do you do X?" without any example code, and so I figured I might as well show my current line of thinking for the sake of clarity.  Also, since I have to pay for EMR time on AWS, trying this out to test its efficiency is not exactly a trivial thing.  Sometimes I have to wait hours for my EMR jobs to finish.

Comment: Hi, I think I can help you, but I'm not sure what the exact form of your input is. Could you give the schema of split_records and updated_volume?

You can get Pig to list the schema of a relation using the DESCRIBE command.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does something along the lines of what you are trying to do.
For each record in updated_volume, it applies all of the corresponding split_records that postdate it.

```
cgrp = COGROUP updated_volume BY symbol, split_records BY symbol;
SPLIT cgrp INTO
    did_split IF SIZE(split_records) > 0,
    did_not_split OTHERWISE;

-- reflatten data for symbols that did not split
not_updated     =   FOREACH did_not_split GENERATE
                        FLATTEN(updated_volume);

-- update data for symbols that did split
to_be_updated   =   FOREACH did_split GENERATE
                        FLATTEN(updated_volume) AS (symbol, volume_date, open, close),
                        split_records;
updated         =   FOREACH to_be_updated {
                        applicable_splits = FILTER split_records BY date >= volume_date;
                        GENERATE
                            symbol, volume_date AS date,
                            -- NOTE: you would have to write a quick udf
                            --       in jython (or java) to calculate the product
                            --       of a bag of numbers
                            open * my_udfs.product(split_records.multiply_by) / PRODUCT(split_records.divide_by)
                            AS open,
                            close * my_udfs.product(split_records.multiply_by) / PRODUCT(split_records.divide_by)
                            AS close;
                    }

updated_volume  = UNION updated, not_updated;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **(condition) ? true : false** for column open and close.